# i2c-dev slowing down a program

Tags: c++, i2c, raspberry-pi2

I am running a simple c/c++ code on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian kernel version 4.1.6-v7+ in order to view the thermal images from my new FLIR Lepton camera. I also want to see the actual temperature of the object I am pointing it at, but as the temperature is expressed as relative to the internal temperature of the camera, I need to call a function
    lepton_temperature()
which requires
    i2c-dev
module to be activated. When I activate it and run the function the program slows down from around 9fps to around two frames **per minute**. I didn't really modify anything in the provided code, so I don't understand why that is happening. Here's the function:

```
int lepton_temperature() {
if(!_connected) {
      lepton_connect();
}
result = ((LEP_GetSysFpaTemperatureKelvin(&_port, &fpa_temp_kelvin)));
return ( fpa_temp_kelvin);
}
```

Without i2c-dev turned on the program works normally, but of course then I am getting a zero instead the temperature value. Anyone maybe has an idea on what is going on and how to solve it/make it faster?

Comment: i2c commands are usually done by `ioctl` which is synchronous. doing many calls might slow down your code.

Comment: i2c-dev module to be activated....doe this mean module needs to be loaded or a function in the module needs to be called??

Comment: Thanks Alex, turned out calling it after every frame that loaded seemed to be causing the slow performance. I didn't even consider it since value of every pixel of every frame relies on that temperature. Therefore I just assumed it can't be it.

Answer (score 0):

It might sound obvious, but your question suggests to me that you overlooked it: use a separate thread for the `lepton_temperature` call.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Why? Blocking calls block a thread, not a whole process.

Comment: Threading adds complexity that probably isn't needed in this case (locks, thread cleanup, and so on). Also, using a separate process makes the results available to any process that wants to read them rather than them fighting over sending requests to the same hardware.

Comment: Nah, just use a `std::atomic<int> temperature`. A separate process needs cleanup as well, which is even harder.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Alex was right, as i2c commands are done by `ioctl` which is synchronous, using the command after each loaded frame was making the program too slow. I didn't consider it as every pixel value of every frame is calculated according to that temperature, so I was sure that can't possibly be the case. Turns out I was wrong.
Thanks to everyone anyway, sorry for posting a question without checking a pretty obvious solution first!